# Error: Datepicker: value not recognized as a date object by DateAdapter when selecting date

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material2

I'm using the [material datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview).

```
<md-form-field [formGroup]="groupName">
    <input mdInput
           placeholder="{{ 'date' | translate }}"
           [mdDatepicker]="picker"
           [formControlName]="controlName"            
           [(value)]="date"
           [min]="min">
    <md-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="picker"></md-datepicker-toggle>
    <md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
</md-form-field>
```

when the view inits it loads perfectly and my `date` variable equals `null`. However when I select a date in the calendar, I receive this error:

`Error: Datepicker: value not recognized as a date object by DateAdapter.`

I've found alot of topics about this error appearing because the component has a string as date, which is not allowed, However my date inits as null, which is allowed.

I assume something is wrong with my databinding?

**EDIT:**
I found out what's causing the problem.

```
<md-form-field [formGroup]="groupName">
    <input mdInput
           placeholder="{{ 'date' | translate }}"
           [mdDatepicker]="picker"
           [formControlName]="controlName"            
           [(value)]="date"
           [min]="min"
           (dateChange)="handleDateChange($event)"
           (dateInput)="handleDateInput($event)">
    <md-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="picker"></md-datepicker-toggle>
    <md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
</md-form-field>
```

when I add

```
           (dateChange)="handleDateChange($event)"
           (dateInput)="handleDateInput($event)">
```

it triggers the error, however the handlers don't do anything special.

```
public handleDateChange(e: any) {
    console.log(e);
    this.dateChange.emit(e);
}

public handleDateInput(e: any) {
    this.dateInput.emit(e);
}
```

When I remove the lines from the datepicker, it works perfectly

Comment: working fine. Can you reproduce your error on plunker or stackblitz?

Comment: datepicker: You must now use a date object (of whatever type your DateAdapter uses) rather
than a string when setting the value of the datepicker programmatically (through value, ngModel,
or formControl). https://github.com/angular/material2/releases

Comment: @SumitAgarwal, the OP has mentioned that he is not using a string. He is using `null` to initialize the `date` object, which should work fine imo.

Comment: @Faisal Editted the OP

Comment: @Nicolas 1. Have you setup a custom date adapter? 2. You are binding to a `FormControl` AND with `[(value)]`. You should only use one. 3. If you remove the `emit()` lines from the change handlers, does it work?

Comment: Note the following github issue: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6265 This means that if you select a date, do some processing and then set the value back to the string representation you will get the error above. Currently you must keep a consistent date object in the system at all times.